# IBM Verse Inbox not syncing

Tags: sync, email, samsung-galaxy-note-4

Our organization is using IBM iNotes Social Edition and have set up a server for emails. I have been using IBM Verse for my emails syncing on my mobile Samsung Galaxy Note 4. It was working fine till last two months. Suddenly, on my Verse app, all emails are being synced except my Inbox. It is not anymore syncing. I have tried many times to get the issue resolved from my Email administrator but the issue persists. The thing that is to be noted here is that Inbox emails are working fine and notifications of my Inbox email arrives on a Web browser. But I am not able to sync it on mobile. All emails are synced on mobile except Inbox which remains empty and no notification of arriving email as well.

Also, note that the emails in apps of all other employees are working fine. Secondly, our mobile emails are synced on a different server as compared to the main server (for web browser emails), they are using some kind of server mirroring (for IBM Verse).

What have I tried:

- Reset and reconfigure IBM Verse Reinstall and reconfigure IBM verse
- Installed IBM Verse on other device and configured
- Reset the device and reinstalled IBM verse and reconfigured
- Requested change of password from email administrator, and reconfigured IBM Verse

None of the methods works to bring my inbox back to sync on the mobile device.

Please help.

Comment: Please suggest where should I post it then?

Comment: I would suggest posting it on ServerFault, and tagging it with lotus-notes and ibm-domino. (There doesn't appear to be a tag for Verse.)